# Best way to build a "task queue" with RxJava

Tags: kotlin, queue, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Currently I'm working on a lot of network-related features. At the moment, I'm dealing with a network channel that allows me to send 1 single piece of information at a time, and I have to wait for it to be acknowledged before I can send the next piece of information. I'm representing the server with `1..n` connected clients.

Some of these messages, I have to send in chunks, which is fairly easy to do with RxJava. Currently my "writing" method looks sort of like this:

```
fun write(bytes: ByteArray, ignoreMtu: Boolean) = 
    server.deviceList()
            .first(emptyList())
            .flatMapObservable { devices ->
                Single.fromCallable {
                    if (ignoreMtu) {
                        bytes.size
                    } else {
                        devices.minBy { device -> device.mtu }?.mtu ?: DEFAULT_MTU
                    }
                }
                        .flatMapObservable { minMtu ->
                            Observable.fromIterable(bytes.asIterable())
                                    .buffer(minMtu)
                        }
                        .map { it.toByteArray() }
                        .doOnNext { server.currentData = bytes }
                        .map { devices }
                        // part i've left out: waiting for each device acknowledging the message, timeouts, etc.
            }
```

What's missing in here is the part where I only allow `one` piece of information to be sent at the same time. Also, what I require is that if I'm adding a message into my queue, I have to be able to observe the status of only this message (completed, error).

I've thought about what's the most elegant way to achieve this. Solutions I've came up with include for example a `PublishSubject<ByteArray>` in which I push the messages (queue-like), add a subscriber and observe it - but this would throw for example `onError` if the previous message failed.

Another way that crossed my mind was to give each message a number upon creating / queueing it, and have a global "message-counter" Observable which I'd hook into the chain's beginning with a `filter` for the `currently sent message == MY_MESSAGE_ID`. But this feels kind of fragile. I could increment the counter whenever the subscription terminates, but I'm sure there must be a better way to achieve my goal.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd be tempted to have an observable of successes and zip that with the observable of requests so that I only get another request when there's a success

Comment: That said... I'd probably just have an actual queue (rabbit, SQS, etc)... then you have an observable that writes to it and one that reads from it. Much easier to use a queue somebody else wrote (cos they are edge cases all the way down)

Comment: Good point, zipping it would also be an option. But then I'd have the problem of separating error emissions, at least in my train of thought? If I have a queue Observable and a success/write-terminated observable and zip them, then I'd merge all write commands from the queue into one Observable and thus I'd be unable to distinguish which of the commands actually threw an exception, or am I missing something

Comment: I'd have a separate observable of errored messages. That should be built to include the message that was sent. Then you can even read either from next unsent message or a failed one after a delay allowing retry. But you'd need to include a count of attempts so you can increase delay on each attempt and fail after n retries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference: The most straight-forward approach I've found is to add a scheduler that's working on a single thread, thus working each task sequential.